# Error in android - Posting data from android to php sql

Tags: java, php, android

I am using the following code to post data from android to sql database through php
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.androidhive.R;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "https://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting error at **pdialog.show()**.
The app crashes exactly at this line.
I am using async task to post the data to the specified url.
What should i change? 
Can you please change the code and post again?

Logcat:

> 06-10 13:40:26.141 4942-4942/? E/WindowManager:
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   videosharing.com.myapplication.NewProductActivity has leaked window
>   DecorView@cb5a3b0[] that was originally added here
>                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:417)
>                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
>                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
>                                                       at videosharing.com.myapplication.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:78)
>                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:613)
>                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:560)
>                                                       at videosharing.com.myapplication.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:58)
>                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Start the new activity only in onPostExecute(). Put the finish() there too and do not use finish() untill all works.

Comment: Can you change the code and post please

Comment: Why should i? Do those things in onPostExecute. Try. Then post updated code here.

Comment: Further you should post the relevant lines from the logcat if your app crashes.

Comment: you are asking me to add the pdialog.show() in post activity

Comment: No. Please reread my comment. I told you exactly what to do.

Comment: @user9578112 Post the error logcat, so that we could help you.

Comment: I have added my logcat

Comment: `private ProgressDialog pDialog;`. Put that in your asynctask class.

Comment: i am getting the same error

Comment: Remove all code from doInBackground. What happens?

Comment: Remove the super.onPreExecute call.

Comment: No error when i remove all code from doInBackground

Comment: Same error when i remove the super.onPreExecute call

Comment: Well then add line for line your code to doInBackground until it crashes again. Just learn to debug. Find the line that causes the crash.

Comment: When i remove pdialog.show() i am getting the following error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at videosharing.com.myapplication.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:100)
                                                                                    at videosharing.com.myapplication.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:63)

Comment: `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest()` returned null. So `json` is null. You should check for null and not continue if null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonParser.makeHttpRequest()` returns `null` probably because you have a `https://` url.

Comment: Should i change the website?

Comment: You should first investigate if this is indeed the reason.

Comment: It is unclear what you did. And which error you have now.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: This is what i did

Comment: Sorry but i will not follow your link.